# Dart: Observable variable not updating

Tags: dart, polymer

I have a Dart app in which I need to set a number of fields based on what's coming back from a JSON request. I'm extending PolymerElement and using @observable to keep the field in sync. What I want to be able to do is to set a global variable and have that drive the class level variable. I'm sure I'm missing something fundamental, but I can't access the object that's being used by the HTML because it hasn't been instantiated (or has it?).

**mobilemenu.dart**

```java
library mobilemenu;

import 'dart:html';
import 'order_item.dart' as orderitem;

main() {}
```

**mobilemenu.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="import" href="order_item.html">
        <script src="packages/polymer/boot.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="mobile-menu-product-name">
            <order-item></order-item>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**order_item.dart**

```java
library orderitem;

import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:json' as JSON;

@observable String g_product_name;

@CustomTag('order-item')
class OrderItem extends PolymerElement with ObservableMixin {
  @observable String product_name = g_product_name;
}

Map processString(String jsonString) {
  // Create a map from json string
  Map jsonParse = JSON.parse(jsonString);
  print(jsonParse);
  return jsonParse;
}

setGlobals(Map jsonMap) {
  g_product_name = jsonMap["details"][0]["product_name"];
  print(g_product_name);
}

main() {

  var baseUrl = "https://example.com/add_item.json";
  var params = window.location.search;
  var fullUrl = baseUrl + params;

  HttpRequest.getString(fullUrl)
    .then(processString)
    .then(setGlobals);

}
```

**order_item.html**

```html
<polymer-element name="order-item">
  <template>
    <div>
      <span>{{product_name}}</span>
    </div>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="order_item.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit--Working Example**

Your real issue is that

```
@observable String product_name = g_product_name;
```

doesn't set `product_name` to `g_product_name`, it sets `product_name` to the **value** of `g_product_name` at the time of assignment, which is null. **Changing the value of `g_product_name` does not change the value of `product_name`.**

I got around it by making a container for your global variable and making the property observable. That way you can set OrderItem property to the same object that your global variable is set to and it will bind the template to the property in your global variable.

**add_item.json**

```
{"details": [{"product_name": "foobar"}]}
```

**order_item.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="import" href="order_item.html">
        <script src="packages/polymer/boot.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="mobile-menu-product-name">
            <order-item></order-item>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**order_item.dart**

```
library orderitem;

import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:json' as JSON;

class GlobalVariable extends ObservableBase {
  @observable
  String g_product_name;
}
GlobalVariable globalVariable = new GlobalVariable();

@CustomTag('order-item')
class OrderItem extends PolymerElement with ObservableMixin {
  GlobalVariable _globalVariable = globalVariable;
}

Map processString(String jsonString) {
  // Create a map from json string
  Map jsonParse = JSON.parse(jsonString);
  print(jsonParse);
  return jsonParse;
}

setGlobals(Map jsonMap) {
  globalVariable.g_product_name = jsonMap["details"][0]["product_name"];
  print(globalVariable.g_product_name);
}

main() {

  HttpRequest.getString("add_item.json")
    .then(processString)
    .then(setGlobals);

}
```

---

It works for me. I replaced your main in order_item.dart with the following and it updated the order item to foobar.

```
main() {
  setGlobals({"details":
    [
      {
        "product_name": "foobar"
      }
    ]
  });
}
```

Obviously example.org/add_item.json isn't a working url, so I'd check to make sure the url is returning what you expect and the json structure is correct. Otherwise, it should work.

Comment: Yes that certainly works! So is my problem the fact that I'm using futures? It almost seems like they take too long and the HTML tries to update before they're done. But I thought the whole point with futures is that it's ok if a process takes its time to finish. How else would I be able to ensure that my JSON has been retrieved?

Comment: Updated my answer with a working example that uses HttpRequest futures.